# Display images dynamically using jquery and thymeleaf

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to display image dynamically by using jquery append function with thymeleaf as view engine in spring boot

Here is the way that I tried to append the image to div ('.show-image'):

```
success: function (data) {
    var image_url = "images.png";
    var images_div = "<img th:src=\"@{/image/"+image_url+"}\" height=\"360px\" width=\"400px\">";
    $('.show-image').append(images_div);
}
```

However, it only shows the empty images (no 404 error)

I tried with other random online image and works:

```
success: function (data) {
    var images_div = "<img src=\"https://onlinejpgtools.com/someimage/random-grid.jpg\" height=\"360px\" width=\"400px\">";
    $('.show-image').append(images_div);
}
```

When I statically display the image also works (I think no path issue):

```
<div class="show-image">
    <img th:src="@{/image/images.png}"  height="360px" width="400px">
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out thymeleaf is a server side technology, which it won't render any new images.

I think my design was wrong, and I just need to render the image without using thymeleaf like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var image_url = "images.png";
    var images_div = "<img src=\""+image_url+ "\" height=\"360px\" width=\"400px\">";
    $('.show-image').append(images_div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have an image under **public/images**. You can use this logic to dynamically set an image:

```
 var myTextNode = $("#base").clone();
 myTextNode.text(msg) ;
 var image_url = "../images/av2.png";

 var images_div = "<img src=\"" +image_url+ "\">";
 myTextNode.append(images_div);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thymeleaf Javascript inline.

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         var myImage= [[@{/image/images.png}]];
    });
</script>
```

Now you can use this myImage javascript variable in your script.